# How to map a square to a triangle?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I need the opposite direction, I was not quite seeing it. I then decided to try and find a transformation from square to triangle in a hope to invert it.

I am trying to find an invertible transformation between the unit square $x,y \in[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and the triangle  $T$ bounded by the coordinate axes and the line $y = -\frac{b}{a}x + b$, ($\xi,\eta   \in T$) .

My way of thinking:
If we fix an $x$ then run though $y$, we want the $\eta $ ordinate to end at $b$ and the $\xi$ ordinate to end at 0. 
$$\xi = ax(1-y)$$
$$\eta = by$$

After a few diagrams I am confident this is correct. I am going to try to use it to simplify an integral so I would like to be sure that this transformation is good before moving on.

EDIT

Putting this in a different way.
I would like an invertible transformation between the unit square defined above and a right-angled triangle bounded by the lines $y = 0$, $x = 0$ and $$y = -\frac{b}{a}x + b$$

This triangle will have vertices $(0,0),(0,b)$ and $(a,0)$.

From the constructive comments, I might have to have the restriction that the area of the triangle and the square must be equal. It is not important that I am mapping from the unit square it just seemed the most simple to begin with.

The transformation that I found is not invertible either. If we consider the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation we find that

$$|J| = ab(1-y)$$ which is $0$ when $y = 1$. So I have failed in that respect.

Comment: 1. We know nothing about your T. 2) By mapping a square to a triangle, do you mean that they are of equal area?

Comment: What do you mean: " We know nothing about your triangle?" I thought it would be clear from  "the triangle bounded by the coordinate axes and the line...". Ah I did not consider whether or not they need to have equal area.

Comment: Well you can work out on your own that you have constrained a valid triangle, now what about defining the type of transformation $T$? Is it a linear transformation, a continuous one, invertible?

Comment: The "T" is referring to that T in $"\xi,\eta   \in T"$.

Comment: That can not be determined from what you have written in the question.

Comment: This cannot be invertible: all the square side with $y=1$ is mapped to a single point. It should be fine if you map only the interior points.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Could you suggest another approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

[image]

Comment: This looks good.

Comment: I will have to take some time to think about how I am going to implement this.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: essentially, split both the square and the triangle in four triangular parts, and map them accordingly to a dilation along a suitable axis.

Answer (score 1):

[From this page](http://www.mathrecreation.com/2009/04/hinged-triangle-to-square.html) !!!.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

[image]