# Map an arbitrary triangle to the unit square

Tags: geometry

As the title say let's define an arbitrary triangle $T = (p_1,p_2,p_3)$ where for all $i \in \{1,2,3\},\ p_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I searched on the net a bijection $f$ that maps $T$ to the unit square, and I found once which is defined by the inverse map as follow  :

$$\forall u,v \in [\![0,1]\!],\ f(u,v) = (1-u)p_1 + u \bigl( (1-v)p_2 + vp_3 \bigr)$$

I spent few hours to understand how the guy is finding this, but no way. Can someone explain me the secret of this bijection ?

Thanks !

Comment: Take care : you don't really get a bijection because point $p_1$ is the image of all $(u,v)=(1,v)$ for any $v \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
p_4&=(1-v)p_2 + v p_3
\end{align}
is a point on the segment $p_2p_3$,
and 
\begin{align}
p_5&=(1-u)p_1 + u p_4 
\end{align}
is a point on the segment $p_1p_4$,
thus running through all $u,v \in [0,1]$
we scan all the area of $\triangle p_1p_2p_3$.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, it's easy enough to map one triangle to another.

If the first triangle has vertices $\mathcal O=(0,0)$, $X_1=(1,0)$, $X_2=(0,1)$ and the second has vertices $a,b,c$ then just use the formula 
$$F_{a,b,c}(x,y) = a + x(b-a) + y(c-a)
$$
To map a triangle with vertices $a,b,c$ to one with vertices $a',b',c'$ just use the formula $F_{a',b',c'} \circ F_{a,b,c}^{-1}$.

Finally to map $T=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ to the unit square, first subdivide $T$ into two triangles by taking $q$ to be the midpoint of the side $p_2,p_3$, hence you have one sub triangle $T_1=(p_1,p_2,q)$ and another subtriangle $(p_3,p_2,q)$. Also, cut the unit square into two triangle $T'_1,T'_2$. Then map $T_1$ to $T'_1$ using one of the earlier formulas, and similarly map $T_2$ to $T'_2$.

Comment: see a similar solution (with a different partitionning by Jack d'Aurizio : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2161070

Answer (score 0):

This the composition of two barycentric operations :

$$\underbrace{(1-u)p_1 + u \underbrace{( (1-v)p_2 + v p_3  )}_{p_4 \ = \ barycenter \ of \ p_2 \ and \  p_3}}_{p_5 \ = \ barycenter \ of \ p_1 \ and \  p_4} \tag{1}$$

that will be more easily seen on Fig. 1. Taking all possible values of $v \in [0,1]$,   $p_4$ sweeps the basis $[p_2p_3]$ ; for a fixed value of $v$, taking all possible values of $u \in [0,1]$,  $p_5$ sweeps the line $[p_1p_4]$. In this way, to any $(u,v) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ corresponds a *unique* point in the triangle, and reciprocally.

In fact, this not exactly true : point $p_1$ is obtained by an infinity of pairs of the form $(1,v)$, $v \in [0,1]$. Thus one doesn't have, truly speaking, a bijection.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Positionning of $p_5$ with $u=1/4 \ vs. 1-u=3/4$ and $v=2/3 \ vs. 1-v=1/3$, these figures being explainable by respective attraction proportionnality.*

Rewriting (1) under the form :

$$p_5=(1-u)p_1 + u(1-v)p_2 + uv p_3 $$

and collecting coefficients, point $p_5$ is represented by its so-called **barycentric coordinates :**

$$((1-u), \ u(1-v), \ uv),$$

introduced with many other concepts in the excellent document : https://team.inria.fr/titane/files/2017/03/barycentric.pdf

Related also : [How to map a square to a triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2160984)